# Angular directive emitting output, parent not updated

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, components, directive

I have an angular component, which is in fact a bootstrap panel.

```
export class ExerciseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() exercise:Exercise;
  @Input() index:number;
  @Input() first:boolean;
  @Input() last:boolean;
  @Input() active:boolean;
  @Input() selected:boolean;
  constructor(private data:ApiDataService, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  toggleActive(e){
    let show = (e.type=='show');
    this.active = show;
  }
}
```

with a template:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div>
    <h5 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionexercises"
         class="accordion-link" href="#collapse{{ exercise.id }}">
        {{ exercise.title }} </a>
    </h5>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <i *ngFor="let n of exercise.difficulty | fill" class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <exercise-preview [hidden]="active" [e]="exercise"></exercise-preview>
</div>
<div id="collapse{{ exercise.id }}" [ngClass]="{'panel-collapse collapse':true, 'in':selected}"
     collapseControl (collapseStatus)="toggleActive($event)">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div *ngIf="exercise.image" class="pull-right">
          <img src="http://localhost:8000{{ exercise.image.file }}"/>
        </div>
        <div [innerHtml]="exercise.exText"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and a directive called `collapseControl` which detects bootstrap collapse events(Jquery) and propagates them my component in `collapseStatus($event)`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[collapseControl]'
})
export class CollapseControlDirective{
  @Output() collapseStatus: EventEmitter<any>;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.collapseStatus = new EventEmitter();
    Observable
      .fromEvent($(el.nativeElement), 'hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse')
      .subscribe(e=> this.collapseStatus.emit(e));
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, event is propagated to parent, `this.active` is set according to an event, but the UI is not not updated (notice the `[hidden]` attribute on `<exercise-preview/>` component).

If I simply change `(collapseStatus)="toggleActive($event)"` to `(click)="toggleActive($event)"` everything works fine. This has to do something with angular change detection, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: does `jquery` tag relates to the question?

Comment: yes, I use jquery to capture bootstrap events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular isn't aware of the changes being made via the `Observable.fromEvent` subscription, as this is not happening within a [zone](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html). You can use [`NgZone`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) to run code within a zone. e.g.:

```ts
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

// ...

constructor(el: ElementRef, ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.collapseStatus = new EventEmitter();
    Observable
      .fromEvent($(el.nativeElement), 'hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse')
      .subscribe(e => {
          ngZone.run(() => this.collapseStatus.emit(e));
      });
}
```

You might be better off using e.g. [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), if you can, in order to have a more Angular-like experience when working with collapsibles, etc, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kirk. I understand that angular does not know about `Observable.fromEvent`, but I thought, that it is aware of EventEmitter which actually emits the signal and value is updated in `toggleActive` handler which has basically nothing to do with the original event. Can you explain this, please?

Comment: Yes, it is *aware* of `EventEmitter`, but not in a change-detection sense. Usually, `emit` is called from within a zone (e.g. after a XHR or DOM event), but there's no magic for Angular to listen in on when these events occur, specifically - it usually "just works" because the action that causes the `emit` is within a zone.

Comment: @MartinM, you can read about separation of event processing and change detection in [Do you really know what unidirectional data flow means in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-really-know-what-unidirectional-data-flow-means-in-angular-a6f55cefdc63)